# Preencher input com result de function javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou usando a seguinte função para validar o CNPJ no Input:

```
function FormataCnpj(campo, teclapres) {
    var tecla = teclapres.keyCode;
    var vr = new String(campo.value);
    vr = vr.replace(".", "");
    vr = vr.replace("/", "");
    vr = vr.replace("-", "");
    tam = vr.length + 1;
    if (tecla != 14) {
        if (tam == 3)
            campo.value = vr.substr(0, 2) + '.';
        if (tam == 6)
            campo.value = vr.substr(0, 2) + '.' + vr.substr(2, 5) + '.';
        if (tam == 10)
            campo.value = vr.substr(0, 2) + '.' + vr.substr(2, 3) + '.' + vr.substr(6, 3) + '/';
        if (tam == 15)
            campo.value = vr.substr(0, 2) + '.' + vr.substr(2, 3) + '.' + vr.substr(6, 3) + '/' + vr.substr(9, 4) + '-' + vr.substr(13, 2);
    }
}



function validarCNPJ(cnpj) {

    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

    if (cnpj == '') return false;

    if (cnpj.length != 14)
        return false;

    // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
    if (cnpj == "00000000000000" ||
        cnpj == "11111111111111" ||
        cnpj == "22222222222222" ||
        cnpj == "33333333333333" ||
        cnpj == "44444444444444" ||
        cnpj == "55555555555555" ||
        cnpj == "66666666666666" ||
        cnpj == "77777777777777" ||
        cnpj == "88888888888888" ||
        cnpj == "99999999999999")
        return false;

    // Valida DVs
    tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
    digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
        soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
        if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
        return false;

    tamanho = tamanho + 1;
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
        soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
        if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
        return false;


    return true;
}
```

chama a mesma dessa maneira:

```
<input ID="txCNPJ_cad_emp" name="cnpj" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o CNPJ" onkeyup="FormataCnpj(this,event)" onblur="if(!validarCNPJ(this.value)){alert('CNPJ Informado é inválido'); this.value='';}" required autofocus></>
```

Se o CNPJ for inválido ela me retorna um alert, porém, ao invés de exibir um alert eu preciso que ela altere outro input

```
<input ID="txCNPJ_cad_emp" name="cnpj">
```

colocando no mesmo a mensagem de erro: "CNPJ inválido".

Comment: @Daniel, os códigos são os mesmos, porém, ela não tem a resposta que é como preencher o Input com o result ou return da function em javascript e se a validação der falsa preencher o input com o texto de erro de validação

Comment: Se era só isso, qual a dificuldade em fazer `this.value = "CNPJ inválido";`?

Comment: Continua sendo duplicata. Basta analisar a solução proposta lá, tal como o Daniel comentou e respondeu.

Comment: ok, @Daniel, funcionou ok sua sugestão, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro remover o teste de retorno de evento declarado direto no elemento pra ficar melhor pra ti visualizar:

```
<input ID="txCNPJ_cad_emp" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o CNPJ" onkeyup="FormataCnpj(this,event)" onblur="verificarValidacaoCNPJ()" required autofocus></>
```

Também alterei um pouco o HTML pra adicionar um id, já que ambos os elementos (inpt do cnpj e da msg de validação) tem o mesmo name.

Tratamento na função chamada no onblur:

```
function verificarValidacaoCNPJ(){
    var valCNPJ = !document.getElementById("cnpj")? "" : document.getElementById("cnpj").value;
    if(!validarCNPJ(valCNPJ))
        document.getElementById("txCNPJ_cad_emp").value = "CNPJ inválido";
    else
        document.getElementById("txCNPJ_cad_emp").value = "CNPJ válido";
}
```

Comment: alterei como você indicou, porém não funcionou e ao debugar ele da a seguinte erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at verificarValidacaoCNPJ (cnpj.html:84)
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur (cnpj.html:53)
verificarValidacaoCNPJ @ cnpj.html:84
onblur @ cnpj.html:53`

Comment: Alterei um pouco a função. Quando tu perde o foco do campo cnpj tem valores lá? Consegue depurar o js?

Comment: funcionou @Aline, é porque tem uma mascara para esse campo dai tava provocando o erro. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Substitui o alert por atribuição do valor do campo:

```
<input ID="txCNPJ_cad_emp" name="cnpj" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o CNPJ" onkeyup="FormataCnpj(this,event)" onblur="if(!validarCNPJ(this.value)){this.value = 'CNPJ inválido'; this.value='';}" required autofocus>
```

Note que na condição `true` está setando valor vazio `this.value='';`. É assim mesmo que pretende?

Comment: obrigado funcionou blz!